# How can I update inner data in firebase realtime database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a new value to the buildVersion object in the following version object. If the market value from the request body matches with market name and needs to add the new value to buildVersion list with a new id. Here is what the database looks like.

[image]

And I tried querying the data using orderByChild like

```
const cMetaData = rootRef.child("/metadata/version").orderByChild('market').equalTo(objRequest[0].market).once("value").then((snap) => {
//here is need to update the buildVersion that matches the Object Request value 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, the following should do the trick if you want to update just one element of the `buildVersion` node:

```
 rootRef
    .child('/metadata/version')
    .orderByChild('market')
    .equalTo(objRequest[0].market)
    .once('value')
    .then((snap) => {
      snap.ref.child('0/buildVersion/0').set('8.15');
    });
```

or

```
 ...
   .then((snap) => {
     snap.ref.child('0/buildVersion').set(['7.15', '8.15']);
   });
```

if you want to update the entire `buildVersion` node.

Comment: Sorry for the misscommunication. I want to update the buildVersion which matches the market Value.

Example:
Consider the objRequest[0].market = 'CORE' and objRequest[0].buildVersion = '8.9' then I need to update the CORE market object with '8.9' so new node looks like.

`
"buildVersion": [
          "6.15",
          "6.16",
          "8.90"
        ],
        "market": "CORE"
`

Comment: What do you exactly mean? That for `CORE` you want to update the `buildVersion` element `0` (i.e. `6.15`) and for `US`the element `1` (`6.16`) -since index of `CORE`is 0 and index of `US` is 1-

Comment: Yes, that's correct. CORE is at index 0 and US is at 1 index. And I want to update the buildVersion of CORE with new value.